# How to create dynamic jar file to get access of multiple classes and its methods from an entry point(main) without importing in java?

Tags: java

I want to access one or many classes from an entry point(main) without importing package. For example:

```
package com.ank.dynamicJarFileCreation;

public class revDemo {
    public static int reverseNumber(int n)
     {
         int rem,rev=0;
         while(n>0)
         {
             rem=n%10;
             rev=rev*10 + rem;
             n=n/10;
         }
         return rev;
     }
}
```

above one is `revDemo` class and I want to access above `reverseNumber(int n)`  method from an entry point below. For example:

```
public class revCall {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    int n=485154;

    System.out.println(revDemo.reverseNumber(n));
```

Or by this way.

```
 Class cls = Class.forName("reverseDemo");
        Object obj =  cls.newInstance();

        System.out.print("Class Name"+cls.getName());
        Object obj =  null; //It is a object of -> com.ank.dynamicJarFileCreationo

        System.out.println(((com.ank.dynamicJarFileCreation)obj).reverseNumber(n));

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want some kind of [Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334578/what-is-dependency-injection)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier  How do I compile Hadoop hbase LZO Compression Decompression Program in Java?
Kindly explain.

Comment: How do I compile Hadoop hbase LZO Compression Decompression Program in Java on windows?

Answer (score 0):

You are very near to your own solution. Actually you created the instance of your required class dynamically using Class.forName() and newInstance() functions.

Next step is to get the Function from the Class by the name of method, say  reverseNumber and execute the same using created instance of revDemo .

```
Class revDemoClazz = Class.forName("com.ank.dynamicJarFileCreation.revDemo");
Object revDemoObj = revDemoClazz.newInstance();
Method reverseNumberMethod = revDemoClazz.getMethod("reverseNumber", Integer.class);
reverseNumberMethod.invoke(revDemoObj, 12345);
```

Comment: I did accordingly but getting Exception like 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ank.dynamicJarFileCreation.reverseNumber(java.lang.Integer)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at reverseCallerFun.main(revCall.java:16)`

Comment: As I can see your actual method signature is like public static int reverseNumber(int n); So to find that method you need get method as revDemoClazz.getMethod("reverseNumber", int.class)

Comment: See the difference at one place we are passing Integer.class and at other int.class as a parameter to method getMethod()

Comment: Yes,I correct it like your way and now there is no any Exception but still it is not doing reverse.
Also let me know if there any way to call non static method.

Comment: At first argument of function  Method.invoke() pass the object of target object, and the non-static method of target object will be invoked.

Comment: your welcome :-) If your problem is resolved please accept the answer.

Comment: As I am new here,when accepting your answers I am seeing pop up comments like: Votes cast by those who has less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score .

Comment: How do I compile Hadoop hbase LZO Compression Decompression Program in Java?
Kindly explain.

Comment: How do I compile Hadoop hbase LZO Compression Decompression Program in Java on windows ?

Comment: Its better to create a new question. It will attract other users too.