# Do we need dependency injection for Model

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

Today, I had a discussion with my colleague about dependency injection for a Model. He strongly believes having DI for a Model. Because he don't want to have concrete object creation.

But what I felt.. DI  needed only in the case where we can replace an implementation with some other. In the case of Business Model it is fixed (if the model is for Automotives it will solve the problems of Automobile only ..  ) and cannot replaced like other technical implementations..

Am I correct or Is there any significance of implementing DI for Business Model ? I felt unnecessary creating interface for each Model as the model is not having any behavior and just DTOs.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"DI [is] needed only in the case where we can replace an implementation with some other."

I agree, and so does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Motivation), "*The primary purpose of the dependency injection pattern is to allow selection among multiple implementations of a given dependency interface at run time...*"

Unless there actually are multiple implementations, DI provides little benefit.
Perhaps the most common answer (e.g. [When to use Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580641/when-to-use-dependency-injection)) is that there are always two implementations: one for production and one for testing. However, modern testing frameworks can mock dependencies effectively without the need for a separate DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely have a need to create interfaces for data model objects. And since data is usually a dynamic part of the app (e.g. reading from the DB or post-marshaling XML from a service call)  it doesn't really exist when the app components are first constructed, which is the most common place you would use DI. This is why it is not typically feasible to represent abstractions in XML and JSON. You would need to add other custom data elements to identify the type in order to solve ambiguity.

So in my opinion, DI for data models is overkill. That said, you should always have a factory and clear separation between the business logic and where the data comes from.